# Run program in virtual machine

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vix

I am using VixVM_RunProgramInGuest to run a executable in a guest virtual machine. If the EXE requires elevation, it fails with the VIX_E_PROGRAM_NOT_STARTED error code. It works fine if the exe is not elevated.

I cannot figure out how to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: `VixVM_RunProgramInGuest` probably isn't UAC aware yet. Try running a batch file which in turn, execute the actual program.

Comment: Thanks I am currently using this trick but it is not very nice.